# Rotate lit LEDs on a 7-segment display

Tags: beginner, assembly

I have written some Assembly code for an assignment, that has me activating the outer bounds of a 7-segment display.
The toggle is every time there is a state change, so both when I flick a switch, and when the switch is returned.
The microcontroller I have programmed is an ATMega32.
How can I make this code more 'crisp'? It looks overly complicated, but I can't seem to figure out how to simplify it. Thanks!

```
.include "m32def.inc"

init:
.DEF    counter=R19
.DEF    switch=R30

reset:
; setup port B (output)
ldi R16, 255
out DDRB, R16 ; setup PORTB as output
out PORTB, R16

; setup port C (input)
ldi R16, 0x00
out DDRC, R16
com R16
out PORTC, R16

ldi R19, 0

pinsetup:
in  switch, PINC
delay:
nop
dec R20
brne    delay
in  R16, PINC
cp  R16, switch
brne    pinsetup

rjmp    main

main:
in  R16, PINC   ; indlæs pins i r16
ldi R20, 100
delay2:
nop
dec R20
brne    delay2
in  R17, PINC   ; indlæs pins i r17
cp  R16, R17
brne    main
cp  R16, switch
brne    count
rjmp    main

count:
mov switch, R16
cpi counter, 0
breq    outa

cpi counter, 1
breq    outb

cpi counter, 2
breq    outc

cpi counter, 3
breq    outd

cpi counter, 4
breq    oute

cpi counter, 5
breq    outf

outa:
ldi R18, 8; load a's værdi ind i R18
com R18
out PORTB, R18
inc counter
rjmp    main

outb:
ldi R18, 4; load b's værdi ind i R18
com R18
out PORTB, R18
inc counter
rjmp    main

outc:
ldi R18, 2; load c's værdi ind i R18
com R18
out PORTB, R18
inc counter
rjmp    main

outd:
ldi R18, 1; load d's værdi ind i R18
com R18
out PORTB, R18
inc counter
rjmp    main

oute:
ldi R18, 16; load e's værdi ind i R18
com R18
out PORTB, R18
inc counter
rjmp    main

outf:
ldi R18, 64; load f's værdi ind i R18
com R18
out PORTB, R18
dec counter
dec counter
dec counter
dec counter
dec counter
rjmp    main
```